# In model, when to use attr_accessor and when to use attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

`attr_accessible` is used by default, but in #250 in railscasts, it uses `attr_accessor` so I'm confused.

In `Authentication from Scratch` tutorial, the code is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password
  ...
end
```

But in the database, it actually stores only password_hash and password_salt, which do not match our attr_accessible and attr_accessor, can anyone explain this a little bit for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr_accessible` specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment. ([source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible))

`attr_accessor` defines a named attribute for this module, where the name is symbol.id2name, creating an instance variable (@name) and a corresponding access method to read it. Also creates a method called name= to set the attribute. ([source](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor))

So, basically, if you need a non-database-backed attribute, use `attr_accessible`. If you need to mass assign an attribute, whether or not it is backed by the db, use `attr_accessible`. If you need to mass assign a non-database-backed attibute, you would use both.

This all makes perfect sense in the context of your updated question. In a migration, the `password_hash` field is added as a db-backed attribute to the model. Then in the code, `password` (and its confirmation) are added as non-database backed attributes. The line `before_save :encrypt_password` calls the `encrypt_password` method before the model is saved. In that method, the database-backed attribute is derived from the non-database backed attributes. The reason you don't need `attr_accessor :password_hash` is because it is never mass-assigned (like `password`), but rather explicitly set. Make sense?

Comment: Is there a type for non-database-backed attribute?

Comment: Nope, it just takes what it gets, with no coercion.

Answer (score 0):

attr_accessor is for creating virtual attributes
attr_accessible is for mass assignment

According to tutorial
attr_accessor :password (because password field  is not in database)
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation (because of mass assignment)

password_salt and password_hash are in only before_save callback so there is no need to write these in attr_accessible or attr_accessor